# One instance of a class at a time

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a class called **TestClass**. I want the application to contain only one instance of this class at a time.

I have a heritable class name **Singleton**, I use it like this :

```
public class TestClass : Singleton<TestClass>
{

}
```

And I use it like this

```
TestClass.Instance // Gives me one instance
```

The thing is, from time to time, I'll need to re-instantiate the TestClass often, with new parameters etc..

Should I make a static instance and just re-instantiate whenever I want, or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks and sorry.

Comment: What changes the values, user input, or is it application reloading static data, or...?

Comment: How does inheriting from `Singleton<T>` help? The `Instance` property is static and cannot be inherited.

Comment: Inheriting from Singleton<T> makes the class have 1 and only 1 instance at a time, that's what I need. Except I need to re-instatiate for each use.
@Brian Mains It's me who changes the values

Comment: The Singleton of GoF days has largely been replaced by dependency injection containers, where your intention that there be only one instance is declared in the container configuration. See this [article](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2016/05/03/singleton-vs-dependency-injection/) for a balanced discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Singleton is meant to be existing until the app is terminated and shouldn't be re-instanitated. If you want to change any member of this class, create setter method.

For instance, if you have a singleton class and two members in it:

```
public int Integer1 { get; private set;}
public string String1 { get; private set;}
```

You can either create two setters or, if these two properties should be changed together, create one method which will set them a given values:

```
public void SetIntAndString(int int1, string str1)
{
    Integer1 = int1;
    String1 = str1;
}
```

There should never exist any way to delete or modify the class instance object itself.

Comment: Seems like a good idea, I think i'll just do methods to re-launch actions from that class with new values, seems good?

Comment: Yes, this is much better idea than reinstanitating singleton